# resource string with flexigrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, flexigrid

I  have just started using `flexigrid` and wanted to use the resource string to display the column but for some reason it is not working.

Like this:

```
{ display: @Resources.stringname, name: 'number',
                                  width: 200, sortable: false, align: 'left' },
```

Has anyone faced this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I forgot to use in single quote like this '@Resources.stringname'.
And that did the trick.